# Ridid Body sim breaks after selecting a different starting frame?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, frame-rate

My ridid body simulation works fine rendering from frame 1, but breaks rendering from frame 60. I was wondering how I can solve this, as I dont want to render 60 frames of nothing (would take about 2 hours more).

Comment: Go to Properties Editor > Scene Properties > Rigid Body World > Cache and click Bake button

Comment: Thank you very much, im kinda new to Blender.

Comment: Welcome to the community :)